# Can't re-enable after disabling button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable "b" button and "c" button by clicking "a". I got it worked but, I want to re-enable "b" and "c" button after clicking "a" button second time. I am new to JavaScript I will appreciate any help I can get.

```html
<button id="a" onclick="getElementById('b').disabled=true; getElementById('c').disabled=true;">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
```

Comment: Please add the reason on the comment section of why the post get down vote

Comment: Use of a function and an event listener, is normally preferred over inline event attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<button id="a" onclick="if (getElementById('b').disabled==false) {getElementById('b').disabled=true; getElementById('c').disabled=true;} else {getElementById('b').disabled=false; getElementById('c').disabled=false;}">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
```

Or you could make it a function for clearer code:

```js
function updateBD(){
    if (getElementById('b').disabled==false){
        getElementById('b').disabled=true; 
        getElementById('c').disabled=true;
    } else {
        getElementById('b').disabled=false;
        getElementById('c').disabled=false;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="a" onclick="updateBC()">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
```

What this function does is that it checks if the b button is enabled (`getElementById('b').disabled==false`) and if it is then it disables buttons b and c (`getElementById('b').disabled=true; getElementById('c').disabled=true;`). Ohterwise it enables them back because they are disabled (`getElementById('b').disabled=false; getElementById('c').disabled=false;`).

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Comment: Please don't post incomplete answers and then edit them after to make them complete. Being first isn't that important, and it's impolite.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<button id="a" onclick="b.disabled=!b.disabled; c.disabled=!c.disabled;">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
```

In HTML5 you can reference elements by their ID (use just `b` instead of `document.getElementById("b")`.
Also, `!boolean` means the opposite of that boolean's value.

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Answer (score 1):

A *smart* way to do that is the following:

```html
<button id="a" onclick="getElementById('b').disabled=!getElementById('b').disabled; getElementById('c').disabled=!getElementById('c').disabled;">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
```

Here you just reverse the *disabled* state by using the *not* operator in Javascript. If you are not familiar with *Javascript* booleans, you can checkout this pretty clear documentation of [W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) which will help you.

Comment: I will check it out.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<button id="a" onclick="getElementById('b').disabled = getElementById('b').disabled==true ? false: true; getElementById('c').disabled = getElementById('c').disabled==true ? false : true;">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
```